# jQuery and concatenating multiple field values

Tags: jquery

How can I make this simpler?:

```
var address = jQuery.trim($("#Address1").val()) + " " + jQuery.trim($("#City").val()) + " " + jQuery.trim($("#State").val()) + " " + jQuery.trim($("#Zip").val());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var address = "";
$("#Address1, #City, #State, #Zip").each(function(){
    address += $.trim($(this).val()) + " ";
});
```

If you are looking for the form text inputs then you can make it simpler as given below:

```
var address = "";
$(":text").each(function(){
    address += $.trim($(this).val()) + " ";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Stack items in an array and loop:

```
var arr = ['Address1', 'City', 'State', 'Zip'];
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    arr[i] = $('#'+arr[i]).val();
}
var address = arr.join(' ');
```